# Swing-up canopy not shut in high-speed flight, what would happen?

Tags: military, emergency, canopy

What would happen to a canopy like that on the Eurofighter Typhoon that swings up if it wasn't shut properly and the plane was going at high speeds, would the canopy blow back open?

Comment: In a civilian aircraft, sadly this could happen: http://www.atsb.gov.au/publications/investigation_reports/2014/aair/ao-2014-164/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

([Source](http://www.scaleworkshop.com/images/828.jpg)) [T-38 Talon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_T-38_Talon)

Yes, it's possible. If it didn't separate, then it needs to be checked after the scary and cold flight is completed.

There will be warnings if the canopy is not closed shut.

[image]

([T-38 Talon Pilot's Flight Operating Instructions](https://books.google.com/books?id=8mBNAgAAQBAJ))